# Can roots be $y$-intercepts for the quadratic function

Tags: polynomials

I know this must be stupid question, but I was wondering why cannot a quadratic or any polynomial equation be in format of
$$x=ay^2+by+c$$

and to find roots we set $x=0$.

In short, can the $y$ intercepts also be roots of quadratic equation?

I searched online and found that $y$ is imaginary and $x$ is real axis but I couldn't understand why polynomial equation when intercept $y$-axis and is solution to equation.

Answer (score 0):

Quadratic and polynomial equations CAN be written in terms of y rather than x. However, it is convention that we use x as the independent variable and y as the dependent one. thats why we always see $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ rather than $$x=ay^2+by+c$$

Comment: but y cannot be the roots be equation right? I don' t know why but I read online because of imaginary and real axis but I couldn't get the idea .

Comment: Yes, y can be root to the equation. But they would be y-axis intercepts, not x axis.
When you read that Y axis was imaginary and x was real you were probably reading about imaginary, numbers, because they are graphed that way (imaginary part on y and real on x)